# Change position of Angular component based on parent property

Tags: angular

I have an angular 2 component that represents a simple control. It has a body and a footer. The user of the control interacts only with the `<my-control>` component, which passes a lot of the properties through to `<the-body>` and `<the-footer>`.

```
selector: 'my-control',
template: `
    <the-body
        [bodyProp1]="bodyProp1"
        [bodyProp2]="bodyProp2">
    </the-body>
    <the-footer
        [footerProp1]="footerProp1"
        [footerProp2]="footerProp2">
    </the-footer>`
```

I'd like to be able to add a property to `<my-control>` that puts the footer above `<the-body>` rather than below it. I could do something like this:

```
selector: 'my-control',
template: `
    <the-footer
       *ngIf="footerPosition === 'top'"
       [footerProp1]="footerProp1"
       [footerProp2]="footerProp2">
    <the-body
       [bodyProp1]="bodyProp1"
       [bodyProp2]="bodyProp2">
    </the-body>
    <the-footer
        *ngIf="footerPosition === 'bottom'"  
        [footerProp1]="footerProp1"
        [footerProp2]="footerProp2">
    </the-footer>`
```

But I don't want to have to repeat the entire `<the-footer>` component again at the top. In the real code there are a lot of properties on it and it would be a maintenance problem to keep both `<the-footer>` components perfectly in sync.

Outside of messing with the CSS `position` values, is there a way to tell angular to reposition the `<the-footer>` component based on the value of the `footerPosition` property?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `<Footer-Container>` component that will render the `<the-footer>` component and try the below structure:

```
   <my-control>

   <Footer-Container *ngIf="footerPosition === top">
   </Footer-Container>

   <the-body>
   </the-body>

   <Footer-Container *ngIf="footerPosition === bottom">
   </Footer-Container>

   </my-control>
```

hope this workaround would save you time to maintain rendering `<the-footer>` component at multiple places.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't really solve the problem. I probably didn't make it clear before, but many of the properties are passed through the parent into the footer (I updated the original post to make this more clear). So you'd end up having to pass all those same properties from the parent into the `<Footer-Container>` which is the same problem.